# How to transfer information between objects in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, object

I'm new to unity and component-based programming. I'm not doing anything visual yet (animation, graphics, etc.) just the logic.

I'm creating a unique card game as a hobby and need some help with lists. I created a PlayerDeck class for the PlayerDeck Game Object in the Hierarchy that loads, shuffles, and deals cards from a database to four players. Here's the code:

```
public class PlayerDeck : MonoBehaviour
{
public int d;
public int w;
public int x;
public int y;
public int z;
public List<Card> deck;
public List<Card> container;
public List<Card> player1hand;
public List<Card> player2hand;
public List<Card> player3hand;
public List<Card> player4hand;
public List<Card> distributed;
public List<Card> discarded;
public int decksize;
void Start()
{

LoadVariables();
LoadDeck();
ShuffleDeck();
DealCards();



}
public void LoadVariables()
{
d = 0;
w = 0;
x = 0;
y = 0;
z = 0;
decksize = 64;
}
public void LoadDeck()
{

for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
{
d = i;
deck[d] = CardDatabase.cardList;
}
}
public void ShuffleDeck()
{
for (int i=0; i<decksize; i++)
{
container[0] = deck;
int rnd = Random.Range(i, decksize);
deck = deck[rnd];
deck[rnd] = container[0];
}
}
public void DealCards()
{
// deal to player one
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
w = i;
player1hand[w] = deck;
distributed = player1hand[w];
deck.Remove(deck);
}
//deal to player two
for (int i=7; i < 14; i++)
{
player2hand[x] = deck;
distributed = player2hand[x];
deck.Remove(deck);
x++;
}
//deal to player three
for (int i = 14; i < 21; i++)
{
player3hand[y] = deck;
distributed = player3hand[y];
deck.Remove(deck);
y++;
}
//deal to player four
for (int i = 21; i < 28; i++)
{
player4hand[z] = deck;
distributed = player4hand[z];
deck.Remove(deck);
z++;
}

}
}
```

So far the logic seems legit. I debugged it and I can see each player getting the right cards from the deck.
Now, I created a Game Object called Player1 and wanted to create a class where Player1 has access to the player1hand list in the Player Deck. Basically, how can I transfer this info to Player1 in code? Here's what I did but I get blanks for Player 1:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof (PlayerDeck))]
public class PlayerHand : MonoBehaviour
{

PlayerDeck playerhand;
public List<Card> dealthand;
public int a;
private void Start()
{

playerhand = GetComponent<PlayerDeck>();
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
a = 0;
dealthand[a] = playerhand.player1hand;
a++;
}
}
```

Any ideas? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you inject/link the two components from the inspector? Try making `PlayerDeck playerhand` public or add `[SerializeField]` attribute to it if it's not showing up on the PlayerHand component in the inspector. Also is your indentation really like that?

Answer (score 0):

Your design doesn't make much sense. Why does the deck own the cards in the hands of the players? Let the hands manage their own cards, and the deck should just tell the hands to take the cards and do whatever they do with them.

I would add a method to PlayerHand called `Add` which takes a `Card` and adds it to their hand.

Each `PlayerHand` should be on a different gameobject. Also, your example code makes it seem like every player draws from the same deck and discards to the same pile, so there is no need for requiring a `PlayerDeck` on the same component as `PlayerHand`

In case the hand needs a reference to the deck at some other point, also add a method called `RegisterDeck` to give the deck reference to the `PlayerHand`.

```
public class PlayerHand : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] List<Card> dealtHand;
    [SerializeField] PlayerDeck myDeck;
    
    private void Awake()
    {
        dealtHand = new List<Card>();
    }
    
    public void Add(Card addedCard)
    {
        dealtHand.Add(addedCard);
    }

    public void RegisterDeck(PlayerDeck myDeck)
    {
        this.myDeck = myDeck;
    }
}
```

Then in `PlayerDeck`, replace your `playerXhand` fields with a single `List<PlayerHand> playerHands` field, and then deal to those players using `AddToHand`. I'm not sure what you were trying to do by assigning a List as an item in a List like `player1hand[w] = deck;` but just remove cards from the top of the list.:

```
public class PlayerDeck : MonoBehaviour
{
    // ...
    [SerializeField] List<PlayerHand> playerHands;
    // ...
    public void DealCards()
    {
        // deal 7 to each player
        foreach (PlayerHand hand in playerHands)
        {
            hand.RegisterDeck(this);

            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                Debug.Assert(deck.Count > 0, "Ran out of cards while dealing");
                Card drawnCard = deck[0];
                deck.RemoveAt(0);
                hand.Add(drawnCard);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in the editor, I would specify the length of `Player Hands` to be 4, and drag the gameObjects that each `PlayerHand` is attached to into that list so that `PlayerDeck` can get to them. Each PlayerHand should definitely be in a different gameObject, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I guess I designed it like this because of the rules of this particular game.  The players don't really pluck from the deck.  The deck is like a casino dealer who gives a card based on a particular rule, sort of like blackjack, but I think I see what your saying.

Comment: I would add a method to `PlayerHand` that looks at the cards in the hand and returns a boolean saying if it should receive a card or an int saying how many cards it should be dealt (depending on the rules, which the question never mentions). Then the deck can ask the hand how many to deal it. Then it can deal that number of cards to that particular player.

Comment: @user3623689 If this answer helped you, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359)